# Sending a data from a server to android device when value changes in a sql database

Tags: php, android, android-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing an Android app that needs to communicate with a server. By that, I mean either the server or the device can send a message at any time. Briefly saying I want to let the user leave the feedback to another user. Something like leaving the feedbacks for example on ebay. Sending a data from android to the server is common and I understand that I can make a http request to run a php script, query a database and send back the response via a JSON object to android device. I would like to inform another user that he received the new feedback via the notifiactions. I know that I could periodically poll the server but I'm trying to avoid this as possible. I have read about Google Cloud Messaging. I'm wondering if there is another simpler or better approach to acheive this task? Please advice. Thank you.

Comment: the term you seem to be looking for is PUSH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you stated in your question, you have 2 options:

- Poll (app polls server to see if there's anything new)
- Push (server tells client that there is something new)

There is no other way how the device could get the knowledge about new stuff on the server (perhaps in a few years, using [quantum entanglement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement) would be a third option ;-)

Push is mosten times better, as network activity only happens if there actually is something on the server.

Comment: server tells client for push not server<->server

Comment: @qaisjp thanks, I corrected it (server<->server wouldn't make much sense)

Comment: I recommend using a push service such as Google Cloud Messaging http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html.polling results in unnecessary calls to your web service which will drain battery and waste the bandwidth

Comment: any links for a good tutorials? what do you think about Google Cloud Messaging. I'm trying to avoid poll due to latency and draining the battery

Comment: Well GCM is the obvious choice here. If your backend is aimed for Android and iOS, you might also want to have a look at Urban Airship (http://www.urbanairship.com)

Comment: are there any advantages of Urban Airship over GCM? I'm aiming an Android

Comment: Hm, urban airship sort of wraps GCM. One advantage, even if you're aiming on Android only is, that urban airship provides you with a backend, so you don't have to set up your own one.